# Weather API and HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, openweathermap

So I was going to make an app that provides you the weather for your current location. Now I know my current coordinate, and I wrote the following code:

MainActivity.java

```
//..... (previous codes obtain the coordinate, and working)
RetrieveWeather mRetrieveWeather = new RetrieveWeather();
t.append("" + mRetrieveWeather.getWeatherReport(mCoordinate));
```

RetrieveWeather.java

```
package com.example.maest.weather;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by maest on 2016/9/28.
 */
public class RetrieveWeather {
        public String getWeatherReport(double[] mCoordinate){
        HttpURLConnection mHttpUrlConnection = null;
        InputStream mInputStream = null;

        try{
            mHttpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=38.868884&lon=-77.053086&appid=myid)).openConnection();
            mHttpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            mHttpUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            mHttpUrlConnection.connect();

            StringBuffer mStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            mInputStream = mHttpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader mBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mInputStream));
            String mString = null;
            while ((mString = mBufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                mStringBuffer.append(mString + "\n");

            mInputStream.close();
            mHttpUrlConnection.disconnect();
            return mStringBuffer.toString();
        }catch (Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try { mInputStream.close();}catch(Throwable t) {}
            try { mHttpUrlConnection.disconnect();}catch(Throwable t) {}
        }

        return "You failed again!";
    }
}
```

Note that the url is valid, although I replaced my appid here.

Everytime I run this code, the TextView displays "You failed again!".

Why???

(p.s. I do have adequate user-permissions inside Manifest)

Comment: You should look at your LogCat, but your problem is probably a NetworkOnMainThread exception

Comment: There are much easier networking libraries to use, by the way

Answer (score 0):

You can't make network requests on the main thread. That's likely the problem, although hard to say without seeing the results print stack trace. I would recommend using a library to make your network requests it will save you a lot of headaches. Look at Retrofit for example http://square.github.io/retrofit/